# Where should I post about computers / gears obsolescence and renewal in a company?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd to ask a question about how a company should manage efficiently to renew its stock of computers. It will be about policy but also the technical and human criteria they should consider for their final choice.

This sounds like this would fit the "workplace" site, but this also quite technical since I think you need some computer skills to answer it.

Do you have any idea where this should go?

Comment: From your description, this is unlikely to be a good fit for any site in the StackExchange network; it would appear to me to be considered "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: I am only interested in facts, but I understand the question could turn the way you describe... so I will try to formulate it a way that will not attract this kind of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour), maybe.

> Server Fault is a question and answer site for managing information technology systems in a business environment. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about server, networking, or related infrastructure administration.

Which seems to cover your need.

Log into any active/applicable chatroom there and pitch the basics of your question there - they'll soon tell you whether it's a fit or not and help you get things into shape, if needed.

Comment: sounds a suited place, yes. I will follow you advice. Thanks

Comment: Eventually, this was not the suited place according to moderator there.  I posted it directly regarding the lack of activity in chat.
https://serverfault.com/questions/954097/what-would-be-a-mutually-beneficial-policy-for-computers-renewal-in-a-company?noredirect=1#comment1240708_954097

Comment: Huh.  So you and I entirely misunderstood what was meant by **"Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment."**

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/954097/what-would-be-a-mutually-beneficial-policy-for-computers-renewal-in-a-company?noredirect=1#comment1240724_954097 
The answer is here. I understand some of the points (though not all), but I will try to find a more suited place anyway.